# Tkinker cursor that impacts a graph

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, cursor

I am not good at all at informatics. 
I don't find anything on the website that explains how to change a value on a cursor that will impact a specific variable in a model that is represented in a graph. With X depending on the time (that is a loop). 
We have the following easy model : X= L + Z + H and the 3 variable that are cursors.

Here is our code for a first cursor with tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *
def sel():
   selection = "Value = " + str(var.get())
   label.config(text = selection)
   print(var.get())
root = Tk()
var = DoubleVar()
root = Tk()
var = DoubleVar()
scale = Scale( root, length = 150, from_=-3, to=5, variable = var)
scale.pack(anchor = CENTER)
button = Button(root, text = "Get Scale Value", command = sel)
button.pack(anchor = CENTER)
label = Label(root)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Thank you very much !